# Replacing capacitors in older electronics

Tags: power-supply, capacitor

[image]I was working on a supplementary power supply board in an old arcade cabinet. It has a capacitor with some markings that I was unable to identify and was curious if they were important. Also, I would like any advice that could help me avoid damaging the arcade.

The markings on the capacitor that I am confused by is "CE04 W". I don't know if this is just manufacturer specific or what? Accordingly, the rest of the capacitor markings are as follow:

25V 4700uf

85 degrees

Comment: Do you have a photo of it? It may not even be a capacitor.

Comment: Based on the 25V 4700uF, I would guess this is a 25v 4700uF Aluminum Electrolytic Capacitor. Any modern one with the same specifications should be fine. The 85C rating is not important... Note new ones may be smaller then the existing one due to technology improvements.

Comment: Add that using a part rated for higher voltage or higher temperature than the current one is generally good for longer lifetime.   You do not need to match those two parameters exactly.   Capacitance, probably best to keep it at 4700uF.

Comment: Post a picture of the power supply it was in. There is no other way to know if there is some other special requirements for the cap or not. It might be standard capacitor if it is in a linear power supply, or it might be a low ESR cap if it is in a switch mode power supply.

Comment: I added a pic. Hope this helps. Thanks again for the responses!

Comment: What a great group! Thanks again for everyone's input!

Answer (score 3):

That's a bulk capacitor for a simple linear power supply, so nothing special is required. It is made by Nippon Chemi-con, so it is not a cheap bad quality capacitor to my understanding. The CE04 W is the capacitor model series, CE04 is very old and at least the datasheet I found on CE04 series does not list capacitors with this high capacitance.

Almost any capacitor with matching capacitance (4700 uF) and matching or exceeding the other parameters is fine. So the voltage must be at least 25V, but it can be more if you can't find a 25V capacitor. The temperature rating may be rated for 85 C due to longevity reasons even if the temperature does not go up to 85 C. So for same reasons, you might want to have the same 85 C rating, or if you can't find one then larger temperature rating is fine.

Comment: Assuming it is a PSU bulk capacitor, a higher capacitance should be fine as well. However, depending on the specific power supply in question, particularly given its age, it may be sensitive to the capacitor's ESR. Also note that a higher voltage rating and higher temperature rating will almost certainly actually be marginally preferable, so if you have options with the same cost, get the better one.

Answer (score 3):

The Nippon Chemi Con CE04W is rated for 2,000 hours at +85 degC: -

[image]

2,000 hours is 83.33 days but, for every 10 degC the capacitor operates at below 85 degC the life time doubles. So at 35 degC average temperature, the lifetime can be expected to be 64,000 hours (2667 days or 7.3 years).

If the voltage actually applied is about 50% of the rated voltage (25 volts) then the operational lifetime doubles again.

See [this calculator](https://www.electronicproducts.com/aluminum_electrolytic_capacitor_life_calculator.aspx#): -

[image]

So, choose a replacement that is good for many years is my advice - if needs be choose one rated at 105 degC or a higher voltage if it helps finding one that fits the space envelope but, whichever you choose look for the lifetime hours in the data sheet - if the capacitor says it's 85 degC rated but doesn't give a number of hours then it's likely to be a poor capacitor. Don't choose a capacitor that hasn't got a temperature rating of at least 85 degC even if it appears to have a lifetime figure.

Also note that the capacitor has a tolerance of +/- 10% or +/-20% and this is usually a sign of reasonable quality because crappy electrolytic caps are usually specified at +80% / -20% in order to overcome their inherent weakening electrolyte over time.

So, choose a decent cap - your arcade machine deserves it!!

So,

Answer (score 1):

It's a 4700uF/25V **aluminum electrolytic** capacitor. Radial package (two leads - at least- coming out of the bottom).

If you go to a distributor such as Digikey and search for capacitors of that value and voltage rating you can find a number. I get 53 that are currently in stock and of those exact values. 
Look at the bottom and see if there is a third hole for mechanical stability.

Try to match the lead spacing so the part will fit down on the board- if the board is really old you may not be able to find one that big without going to a higher voltage rating (higher is fine). Personally I would use a 105°C rated part so it will last longer.

When you install the new one you have to make sure you observe polarity. On aluminum electrolytic capacitors the polarity is indicated by a stripe on the NEGATIVE side. If you don't get it right, the new capacitor will vent noxious electrolyte and you might blow a fuse or worse.

Answer (score 1):

This type of **radial aluminum electrolytic capacitor** is known as a **"snap-in"** cap. The pins are crooked to make it hold onto the PCB so it doesn't fall off when you turn it around to solder it.

[image]

These usually last a very long time.

On the picture, I see a rectifier bridge right behind the cap, so that means it's a power supply smoothing cap. This means characteristics don't matter much as long as it has a voltage rating and capacitance equal to or higher than the old one.

To pick a proper replacement cap, make sure it fits, so check pin spacing. These caps are available in plenty of diameter/height combinations. Since the diode bridge is very close, make sure the new cap isn't too wide. Height may be a factor if some other device in the arcade cabinet is mounted right above the board, so check that too. Also look if the original has more than two pins, if this is the case check which pins are for mechanical stability and which are for electrical connection.

Since modern technology squeezes more µF into a smaller size you may have to get a higher value cap to get the correct pin spacing.

Get a snap-in cap which will have thick crooked pins as shown on the pic above. A standard radial cap will have much thinner pins, thus plenty of empty space left in the holes, which makes soldering more difficult and less reliable.